# How to send a VF template but override the To address?

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

So we have a trigger that automatically emails a Case Contact when a new Comment is added.

However for some users, we require that email to go to an alternate email address, *NOT* the one in the Contact's "Email" field.

How would this be done?  How do you force Apex to use a particular email address, when also using a Visualforce Template?

thanks

Comment: Your trigger is using Apex SingleEmailMessage class?  Or are you executing a trigger and then using workflow+email alerts to send the email?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SingleEmailMessage in a trigger to send the email.  The issue is that when you use a VF template, I don't think you can specify the "To" addresses, you have to link it to an actual Contact, Lead, or User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at an example I implemented some time back, when using SingleEmailMessage with a VF template, you must invoke `setTargetObjectId(targetObjId)` on the object of type `SingleEmailMessage`. And `targetObjId` must be a Contact, Lead or User.

- You can specify additional To recipients by calling `setToAddresses(..)`, passing in a list of email addresses.  Note that the SFDC Apex documentation is wrong here - it says `Optional. A list of email addresses to which you are sending the email. The maximum number of email addresses allowed is 100. This argument is allowed only when a template is not used.`  This is not true, you can use with a template.
- `targetObjId` is used by the VF template if needed to supply merge fields like **Dear {!recipient.firstName}**. In effect, as per the doc, `targetObjId` references the standard controller for Contact, Lead, or User.
- But, if your VF template doesn't use `{!recipient.xxx}`, then you can do what I ended up doing which was create a dummy Contact `no-reply@mydomain.com` with corresponding email address and use that as `targetObjId`. In your example, the real recipients were unconditionally set using the `setToAddresses(..)` method call on SingleEmailMessage

Not a perfect solution but to the intended recipient, they will receive the email as if they were the intended recipient. The recipient is already conditioned to ignore the no-reply email address in the To: line

Here is my Util.sendTemplatedEmail method; you can adapt as needed; the caller is responsible for reserving the email message before invoking to avoid governor limits

```
//  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  sendTemplatedEmail
//  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static void sendTemplatedEmail(String[] toRecipients, String[] ccRecipients, String templateParmName, ID targetObjId, Id whatId, ID orgWideEmailId, Boolean saveAsActivity ) {
    //  templateId  must be ID of an Email template
    //  targetObjId must be a Contact Id -- also used in merge fields of template recipient.xxxx
    //  whatId      must be an SObject that is used in the merge fields of the template relatedTo.xxxx
    //  fromId      if non null, use current user, otherwise, use this ID (most likely an org wide no reply id)
    //  bcc         not permitted when using templates

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String templateApiName = EnvironmentVariable.getString(templateParmName);  // Uses custom setting to allow dynamic switching of email template name .. details not included
    Id templateId;  
    try {templateId = [select id, name from EmailTemplate where developername = : templateApiName].id;}
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MyException ('[UTIL-06] Unable to locate EmailTemplate using name: ' + templateApiName + 
                                    ' as indicated in Custom Settings ' + templateParmName);
    }


    email.setToAddresses(toRecipients);
    email.setCcAddresses(ccRecipients);
    email.setTargetObjectId(targetObjId);
    email.setWhatId(whatId);
    email.setorgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideEmailId);
    email.setTemplateId(templateId);
    email.setSaveAsActivity(saveAsActivity);            // save email as activity on the targetObjId (i.e. Contact)

    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'** entered sendTemplatedEmail, to:' + toRecipients + ' cc:' + ccRecipients +  ' templateId:' + templateId + ' targetObjId:' + targetObjId + 
                                    ' whatId:' + whatId + ' orgWideEmailId: ' + orgWideEmailId);
    try {
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
        return;
    }
    catch (EmailException e) {throw new MyException('[UTIL-07] sendTemplatedEmail error. ' + e.getMessage());}

}
```

Comment: Fantastic!  It didn't occur to me to use a dummy contact, since the setTargetObjectID() is required with a VF Template.

I created a dummy, and if the Contact has 'Use alternate email' set, then it sets the dummy contact as the TargetObjectID, and puts the Alternate email in the setToAddresses().

It works great, thank you for your response!!

Comment: By the way, I was suprised to find that it still correctly populates the {!recipient.xxxx} fields in the template, even when sending to a dummy user.  I think the fact that the template is still linked to the Case record, it still pulls the related merge fields from the Case's Contact, rather than the one i specify in setTargetObjectId()!

Comment: @DownstairsB - I'm a bit surprised as well by your last remark as {!recipient.xxx} should be the standard controller for the `targetObjectId` (the dummy Contact). `{!relatedTo.yyy}` would be the Case and any lookup fields from the Case (including the Case's Contact) would be available as in `{!relatedTo.contact.email}`. I would encourage you to submit your findings as part of the VF Doc 'Feedback' link at the bottom of the doc page.

Comment: Oops, my mistake.  On the template I was testing with, I actually did use {!RelatedTo.Contact.Name} so it was unaffected by changing the recipient.  Thanks.